# Relative Path Basics

Tags: php, html

Although I have a fair idea of relative path but I am a little confused while using this particular relative path in a program. Please someone guide me through. I have the following directory structure:

[image]

The problem here is that I want to include `config.php` file in `left.php`, for that I have given a relative path, `include(../../layout/config.php);` but somehow this is not being included and the relative path that I have to use is `include(../layout/config.php);`. Can someone please explain why is that so? Because my knowledge says that I will have to leave `includes->admin` and then enter `layout`.

Comment: You can always use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to go back to root dir. In your case that would mean `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/layout/config.php";` I find that easier than to use relative paths

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `../../` is 2 ups from the `Source Files` because I have to exit `includes` and `admin` directories.

Comment: @Andreas Haven't actually used `$_SERVER[ ]` as yet which is why don't have idea as to how I could use that. But I guess, I will give it a try too. Thanks!

Comment: Well... You could just look at my comment. I did not include the include but sure, I can do that too. `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/layout/config.php");`

Comment: Question. What file do you run? Is it index.php?

Comment: @Andreas I am going to run `index.php` in the `admin` folder.

Comment: @Andreas Tried your way but I am not able to login after using precisely what you suggested. Although, I don't get the point what relation it has with `$_SESSION`(trimmed spaces, tried removing the `/` before layout).

Comment: I'm very surprised that does not work. What does this return: `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/layout/config.php";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP it's the working direcory that is used as the main path.
All relative paths originate from that folder.

As you wrote in comments you use index.php which is one folder lower than left.

I assume you are in index and include left.php, this does not update the working directory.
Your working directory is still "admin".

You can find out what the working directory is using `echo getcwd();`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

As I wrote in comments you can use `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/Electronix_Store/electronix/layout/config.php");` to use full path instead.
This is easier if the files and folders are in the same position all the time.
My advise is to only use relative paths if you are working with day "user/123/" -> some folder structure in there.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was caught up in some work. O/p of `echo getcwd();` is `C:\xampp\htdocs\Electronix_Store\electronix\admin`. But as you can see, outside of admin, there is another directory, `layout`, and the `config.php` file is in that directory. So the problem now is how to access that file. As told by you, I tried the command, `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/layout/config.php");` but the result was that I wasn't able to login. I am working on the backend of the portal right now i.e `admin` folder and I want to access the files from another folder. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: What does `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/layout/config.php";` return?

Comment: Then it's quite obvious what is missing. "/Electronix_Store/electronix/" apperantly your server root is past the project

Comment: Can you give me the final answer? What should I use? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Very many thanks to you, the thing works but I still haven't been able to figure out how this works exactly, can you plz link me to a few resources to study about it further and does it also work with IIS?

Comment: I guess, there is a difference between the `Server Root` and `Project Root`. Is it?

Comment: Don't know what iis is. But think of it as the page you load is the start directory. In your case you started at /admin/index.php that means admin is the working directory. then I assume you included /layout/left but the working directory I still admin. That has not changed. So when you try to "../../" you go back two steps from admin, not layout. You can change the working directory with http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php but trust me that will open a big can of worms. Not sure if there is such a thing called project root. But usually you are directed to project root in win enviro.

Comment: Have you used MS DOS? You know you could be in c:\ and type `c:\mouse\mouse.exe` and when mouse was loaded you still got back to c:\. Or you could `cd mouse` then `mouse.exe` and you where in c:\mouse\ when it was loaded. It's the same thing on php

Comment: Aahh, I kindda get it. It is like my working directory is `admin` and when I have to get out of admin, I use `../`. But I was of the thinking that first inorder to exit `includes` I will use a `../` and then to exit `admin`, I would use `../`. Thanks a lot for helping me out.